# Winforms WebBrowser webpage triggering event in the winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms application. On my form I have a webbroswer control. It hosts a web page. When an event is fired on the web page, such as clicking a button I wish to Hide() the form and therefore the webpage. Is this possible?

Comment: Sally do you have control over the html page shown in the web browser or you are looking to intercept a button click on any possible web page of the Internet?

Comment: I do have control of the webpage. It is an ASPX page.

Answer (score 2):

You might be trying to do something more sophisticated than what Im about to suggest, but you could handle the Navigating event on the web browser control. Perhaps do something like this:

```
this.webBrowser1.Navigating += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(this.webBrowser1_Navigating);

private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e) {
    e.Cancel = true;
    webBrowser1.Visible = false;
}
```

Of course the e.Cancel will prevent the navigation request from happening (if that is what you want).